# ClickOnce InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse) wrong URL only for some users

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce, manifest

One of our customers has a problem deploying our ClickOnce application. Notice that he is the only one that has problems and all others deploy successfully. In the log we can see a "wrong" URL. The details log file:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1
    System.Deployment.dll         : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfdll.dll             : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll             : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url            : http://download.sandboxmodel.com/ptb/PTB.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://download.sandboxmodel.com/ptb/PTB.application (correct URL) resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from
http://wrongurl.htm?Time=05%2FJan%2F2012%3A14%3A27%3A13%20-0600&ID=4919900&Client_IP.... the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 3.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [1/5/2012 2:27:13 PM] : Activation of http://download.sandboxmodel.com/ptb/PTB.application (correct URL) has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [1/5/2012 2:27:13 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from 
http://wrongurl.htm?Time=05%2FJan%2F2012%3A14%3A27%3A13%20-0600&ID=4919900&Client_IP.... the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Xml.XmlException
        - Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 3.
        - Source: System.Xml
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.Throw(Exception e)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.Throw(Int32 curPos, String res, String arg)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.ScanSubsetContent()
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.GetToken(Boolean needWhiteSpace)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseSubset()
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

We publish from Visual Studio 2010 using .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile, without any "special" settings.These are some settings:
The application is available online only
Enable ClickOnce security settings with full trust
The manifests and the assemblies are signed

I verified with the customer he is using the Internet Explorer browser when trying to deploy.
Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: File corruption has numerous possible causes.  Your customer needs help from her IT staff to get the machine stable again.

Comment: Why do you think that the customers' machine is not stable and that the file is corrupted? I'm thinking more of a network issue. I don't understand why ClickOnce tries to deploy from the wrong URL.

Answer (score 1):

This means you should have latest .NET installed on your system.
Try https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137

Answer (score 0):

We see this issue when the URL is redirect to e.g. a login page of a public WLAN. As we require updating, the user can't start up the application as long as the WLAN adapter is enabled.

Comment: In my  publish settings I disabled updates and the customer still have the issue. What exactly do you mean by the URL redirecting to a login page of a public WLAN? Is this some network setting in the client's network? Did you find some way to fix the problem?